# Background transparent not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/dBeZmkPXSb) and let me know why the CSS rules of
`background-color: transparent;` are not functioning on bootstrap panel body?

```
#collapseOne .panel-body { background-color: transparent; }
.panel-body { background-color: transparent; }
```

Comment: You have to override the `.panel-default` for its `background-color` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not applying the CSS in right place.
You should apply your background transparent in `<div>` having class `pannel Default`.

[Here is the running Example:](http://www.bootply.com/jQNVm13fwg)

Here is the Example:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style='background:transparent'>
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group Item #1
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

I have written Inline CSS just for example to show.But don't go with it.
To make permanent effect navigate to your bootstrap CSS file and change this line

```
.panel{
    background-color:#fff;
  }
```

to this one

```
 .panel{
    background-color:transparent;
  }
```

It will make all your panel's background transparent.

Answer (score -2):

Also, never, ever forget to use !important.

```
background-color:transparent !important;
```